# Vus.js Actions or Global Methods

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using `nuxt.js` and I just learning about store actions. Currently I have made a global mixin where I'm putting all my global methods and computed properties.

I have a bunch or Axios requests that get certain products that I have in my gobal methods in my global mixin.

Is this where I should now move my axios requests to my store actions?

Would I Dispach to my action that uses axios to fetch my data and then commit the returned promise to my store?

Also for best use, would keep your store actions inside the store... eg:products only stuff? Or could you use your action inside of products to get the products, commit it to the store and then send the products to Google Analyitics?

I'd just like a bit of clarification around Actions and the best use of them vs creating global methods or having methods inside of components.

Answer (score 1):

You are spot-on! Dispatch an action, do async axios requests in the action and commit mutations when the axios Promise resolves.

I did not get the second part of your question, if you clarify that I can edit this answer.

Comment: thanks...so my global methods in my mixins to go into my store actions? The other part was that in my actions like product actions, can I do other things in them like once I get the callback from my store, pass other things to my application, like get products and also commit them... (then)=> send products to google analytics, (then)=> add the product to cart etc? So Actions are like methods but you can do other stuff and have access to context?

Comment: Yeah you can do all kinds of stuff in actions and use the context, like commit first, then do some async call and commit again inside the async callbacks etc.

Comment: Also...One more thing... are your actions thin and your mutations fat? Meaning where is most of your logic supposed to be? in the action or in the mutation?

Comment: It depends.. but as a general rule I'd say put logic in actions and have them commit one or more (simple)  mutations to update your state.

Comment: Yep thanks...thats what I thought as actions are do things and multiple things and mutations are do this or something